# Recoger token en webservice Oauth2 con restsharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, oauth2, restsharp

Introduzco la Url y las credenciales  pero me devuelve un json con el resultado:

```
{\"error\":\"invalid_request\"}"
```

Por lo que entiendo que hay comunicación con el webservice solo que la autenticacion no ha funcionado.
La manera de autenticar es la siguiente:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://mi.dominio.com/Identity/connect/token");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("miUsuario", "miPassword");
var request = new RestRequest("",Method.Post);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Con Postman recibo el toquen con esta configuracion:

```
Type: OAuth2
Add authorization: Request Headers

Grant Type: Client Credentials
Access Token URL: https://mi.dominio.com/Identity/connect/token
Client ID: miUsuario
Client Secret: miPassword
Client Authentication: Send As Basic Auth header
```

Esta es la salida de los "request" en la consola de Postman cuando devuelve el token:

```
POST https://mi.dominio.com/Identity/connect/token

Request Headers
  Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  Authorization: "Basic bWlVc3VhcmlvOm1pUGFzc3dvcmQ="
  User-Agent: "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2"
  Accept: "*/*"
  Cache-Control: "no-cache"
  Postman-Token: "bc94c568-f443-4396-9262-54483525bejk"
  Host: "mi.dominio.com"
  Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate, br"
  Connection: "keep-alive"
  Content-Length: 29

Request Body
  grant_type: "client_credentials"
```

Comment: Deberias colocar la especificacion que te dieron para enviar datos al endpoint de "connect/token". porque estas enviando como "HttpBasicAuthenticator" y generalmente estos endpoint de oAuth2 deben recibir una serie de parametros (clientId, clientsecret, scopes, user, password, y el tipo de  credenciales o flujo que necesitas, etc). Si tiuenes usaurio password seguramente el flujo es "ResourceOwnerPassword" . Pero comentanos mas. Que tipo de flujo necesitas, que datos que tienes o te enviaron para obtener el token? (solamente user/pass)?

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez es una autenticacion basica. Por ejemplo con Postman puedo recibir el Token como:  Type: OAuth 2.0, Authorization data to: Request Headers en Configuration Options: Token Name: MiToken, Grant Type: Client Credentials, Access Token URL: https://mi.dominio.com/identity/connect/token, Client ID: miUsuario, Client Secret: miPassword, Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header

Comment: Puedes colocar el codigo de Postman que envias en el cuerpo? o la imagen (mas alla que colocas las variables con valores) porque asi reproducimos exactamente los encabezados en el request que necesites.

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez he añadido los request que devuelve la consola de Postman para recibir el token. Sobre las credenciales el request las pasa codificada en Base64 con el string  miUsuario:miPassword y da bWlVc3VhcmlvOm1pUGFzc3dvcmQ=

Answer (score 1):

intenta asi:

```
public async Task<string> GetAutorizacionAsync()
        {
            string respuesta = string.Empty;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("usuario"+ ":" + "password");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");
                Uri url = new Uri("https://mi.dominio.com/Identity/connect/token", UriKind.Absolute);
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "clientCredentials"));
                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                else
                    respuesta = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }

            return respuesta;
        }
```

Comment: Funciona pero he tenido que llamarla con este codigo ya que uso metodos sincronicos. var result = AsyncContext.Run(GetAutorizacionAsync);  A ver si hay otra solucion pero con  metodos sincronicos.

Comment: Convierte el metodo en sincronico : ya no  devolveria un Task<string> sino simplemente un string , ademas remplaza await client.PostAsync  por solo client.Post